# Detect page/document weight on load - javascript/PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I was wondering how I can detect document weight on page load just like how we see on chrome networks tab and display the data within my site. Thanks!

[image: Reference]

Comment: There is not going to be a "magic" solution which automatically intercepts all requests including CSS, JS, Ajax results, images, the HTML itself, etc. It's going to be some kind of hack _(something like this: look for stuff on the page, and get their size, maybe using Ajax and retrieving the Content-Length headers)_. But that's probably not very reliable. The most reliable solution I can think of is to run your pages server-side in [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer), and simply intercept all requests, but that would probably need to be done once, not on every request